# Do Rust match statements require commas?

Tags: syntax, rust

Why does this code work? Are commas in match statements just a convention?

```
for (index, character) in argv[1].chars().enumerate() {
match character {
    'a' | 'A' => {println!("{}: 'A'", index)}
    'e' | 'E' => {println!("{}: 'E'", index)}
    'i' | 'I' => {println!("{}: 'I'", index)}
    'o' | 'O' => {println!("{}: 'O'", index)}
    'u' | 'U' => {println!("{}: 'U'", index)}
     _        => {
                     let consonant: Vec<_> = character.to_uppercase().collect();
                     println!("{}: {:?} is not a vowel", index, consonant[0])
                 }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Let's take a look what [the Rust reference says about this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/match-expr.html):

> ```
> MatchArms :
>    ( MatchArm => ( BlockExpression ,? | Expression , ) )*
>    MatchArm => ( BlockExpression | Expression ) ,?
> ```

What we can see here is that on the right side of `=>` there is always an expression, but we distinguish between two types of expressions: *BlockExpression* and *Expression*. After a *BlockExpression* a comma is optional (denoted by the `?`), but after an normal expression the comma is required, except for the last match arm: there, the comma is always optional.

What is a *BlockExpression*? [The reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/block-expr.html#block-expressions) defines it as basically two braces `{ }` with a list of statements and an optional tail expression.

So: **commas at the end of match arms are optional if:**

- **it is the last match arm**, **or**
- **if the right hand side of the arm is a block expression (stuff between two braces `{}`).**

---

Unfortunately, the compiler doesn't quite agree with the reference. This works, for example:

```
match true {
    false => if true {
        "hi"
    } else {
        "no"
    }
    true => ""
};
```

Note that the right hand side of the first match arm is not a block expression, but an if-else-expression. So for the compiler the rule seems to be: if the right hand side ends with a closing brace `}`, the comma is optional.

---

As for **what is idiomatic**:

- If the right hand side ends with a closing brace `}`, omit the comma.
- If not: use a comma, even when it's the last match arm.

Answer (score 7):

> Do Rust match statements require commas?

No. *Your own code proves that*.

> Why does this code work?

Because the designers of the language decided it should.

A *match arm* can have either an expression followed by a comma or a block without a comma.

> Are commas in match statements just a convention?

No. When using braces, rustfmt removes the commas. Otherwise they are **required**.

How rustfmt puts your code:

```
for (index, character) in argv[1].chars().enumerate() {
    match character {
        'a' | 'A' => println!("{}: 'A'", index),
        'e' | 'E' => println!("{}: 'E'", index),
        'i' | 'I' => println!("{}: 'I'", index),
        'o' | 'O' => println!("{}: 'O'", index),
        'u' | 'U' => println!("{}: 'U'", index),
        _ => {
            let consonant: Vec<_> = character.to_uppercase().collect();
            println!("{}: {:?} is not a vowel", index, consonant[0])
        }
    }
}
```